# Sound stops working after pressing a key 53 times

Tags: javafx, audio

I'm creating a game in JavaFX (something like Space Invaders) and I'm having problems with the shooting sound, particularly when I press a key quite a few times not only the sound stops being played but other sounds also stop working.

I've done some small research and it seems that this kind of problem is fairly popular and it involves releasing the MediaPlayer object/instance but I can't call that method(?).

I've tried using dispose() method but it disables the shot sound completely.

I have two classes, GameApp:

```
primaryStage.getScene().setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE && playable) {
                    Audio.playPlayerShotSound();
                }
            }
        });
```

and Audio:

```
public class Audio {

    private static Media shot = new Media(new File("resources/playerShot.wav").toURI().toString());

    public static void playPlayerShotSound() {
        MediaPlayer shotSound = new MediaPlayer(shot);
        shotSound.setVolume(0.2);
        shotSound.play();
    }
```

I've created another class using JavaFX and the sound stops after pressing Space 64 times.

```
package examples;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import java.io.File;

public class GameInst extends Application {

    Pane root;

    private AnimationTimer timer;
    private static Media shot = new Media(new File("resources/playerShot.wav").toURI().toString());
    int count = 0;

    private Parent createContent() {
        root = new Pane();
        root.setPrefSize(500, 500);


        timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                onUpdate();
            }
        };
        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                onUpdate();
            }
        };
        timer.start();

        return root;
    }

    private void onUpdate() {
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        root = new Pane();

        primaryStage.setTitle("Space Invaders");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));

        primaryStage.getScene().setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            switch (event.getCode()) {
                case SPACE:
                    MediaPlayer shotSound = new MediaPlayer(shot);
                    shotSound.setVolume(0.1);
                    shotSound.play();
                    count++;
                    System.out.println(count);
            }
        });
        primaryStage.show();
    }

        public static void main (String[] args){
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @kleopatra hey, I edited my post with adding another simple class. I don't know if it's what you've asked but it pretty much replicates my problem.

Comment: cool, thanks :) will try it out next time I'm on a real computer (on mobile right now) .. how are the timers related to what you want to do? And why two of them, starting only the last?

Comment: @kleopatra actually they are probably not related at all :D As a matter of fact I'm quite a novice so I remember copying that part of a code and then not really thinking about it later. Thanks for brining that up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you are trying to do the AudioClip class is probably much better suited as the full blown MediaPlayer. It also probably not a good idea to initialize a new player every time you get an event.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm just gonna rewrite the code using only AudioClip instead of MediaPlayer : )

Comment: @yomi Your issue might be related to the fact you create new `MediaPlayer` instances (as noted in the answer) and never invoke [`MediaPlayer#dispose()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#dispose()) when they complete. However, it'd be better to _reuse_ `MediaPlayer` instances anyway. The same goes for `AudioClip` (which I agree is probably the better choice for your situation).